# How to get current Region Name using Coordinates?

Tags: iphone

I just need current location details,

I have done the part of getting Current location Coordinates.

Now i want to get the region name, etc (No Maps) details using these coordinates.

How to do that? Any sample code available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

implement the `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate`

```
implements <MKReverseGeocoderDelegate>
```

Add an instance variable:

```
MKReverseGeocoder *_reverseGeocoder;
```

Create your reverse geocoder object:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = latitude;   // You said you had this value
location.longitude = longitude;   // You said you had this value
_reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc]initWithCoordinate:location];
_reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
[_reverseGeocoder start];
```

Implement the following delegate function:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark  
{
    /// placemark has your location!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use MKReverseGeocoder.